# BottomNavigationView goes up when keyboard appears using Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, bottomnavigationview

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674965/bottomnavigationview-goes-up-when-keyboard-appears) doesn't work for WebViews, [this doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/how-to-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android) either. So this question is specifically for when using a WebView. Below code loads a webpage with a text input field. When clicking the text input field, the keyboard comes up.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.textFavorites);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.journaldev.com");

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_favorites:
                                webView.loadUrl("https://www.journaldev.com");
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/textFavorites"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Androidmanifest.xml:**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    </activity>
```

**bottom_navigation_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_favorites"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this code in your layout.. I tried it for myself and it's working...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/textFavorites"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textFavorites" // add this line to your code
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see I added `android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textFavorites"` this line in the bottom navigation view and it's sticking at the bottom...

And remove the line 
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

but it hides the text fields also...and keeps the bottom navigation view behind keyboard..

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code and it works. Do the following changes to your code

**First, Add adjustpan to your activity in manifest.**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**Second, Change your layout as below.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/textFavorites"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Last, Change your java code as below

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.textFavorites);
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());  //add this or load url will open in browser instead of webview
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.action_favorites:
                                webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

I have tried with google, and result is as below.

1) With keyboard closed.

[image]

2) With keyboard opened.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Use Constraintlayout instead of Relativelayout because you are making it hard to remove view and if you code work there will **be white space after view gone**. SO use Constraint layout.Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_view" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then create a interface or simply use method

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // hide bottom navigation bar
    }
});
```

you can also call this method in bottom navigation. Also make sure your UI must be proper and better.So if you hide v

Comment: I only want to hide the bottom navigation bar if the user's keyboard slides up. Your code would make it disappear on every onPageFinished...